# Communication while setting up an informational interview via email

Tags: politeness

For an engineering class I'm taking, I've been interviewing experts in the field. The goal of these interviews is to:

1. learn important information on our potential customers.
2. find out more about the terminology to use.
3. discuss previous solutions to the potential problems my group is tackling.
4. find narrower problems within this field to design our solution around.

A government office I contacted by email just set me up with a specific person (a government employee), cc'd this person, and told me to contact this person by email and arrange the date and time. According to the person who arranged this, "they were happy" to speak to me.

I've always read that one should thank a person for their time after an interview, but I haven't had the interview yet, so I'm confused as to what to write.

**Should I thank them for choosing to accept being interviewed**, then ask about possible dates and times?

Comment: Clarification: what do you expect from us? Asking "how should this email be written" seems like asking us to write the email draft for you, which is a "phrasing request" and off-topic here. Asking *guidelines* of how such email be written, however, is on-topic. Then, you can write your own email using the guidelines. Which one you are asking?

Comment: @Vylix - I meant to ask for guidelines. What I really want to know about is whether to thank the person for choosing to be interviewed. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @SnowingSilently "should I thank them" seems a rather obvious "yes". Why do you ask? Do you suspect that this person is actually not willing to be interviewed? What this person is to the government office? An employee?

Comment: @Vylix I don't know anything about this person other than that they are a government employee, and that they were "happy to speak with me," according to the person that helped set this interview up. I've always read that one should thank a person for their time after an interview, but I haven't had the interview yet, so I'm confused as to what to write. Should I write "Thank you for taking the time to let me interview you?" then ask about possible dates and times?

Comment: Have you done any research? There are lots of sites out there that will help you with the interview process, how to word emails, how to write resumes, etc. I recommend looking at that first and then editing your question if you have a more specific problem.

Comment: I have, but I haven't found anything about thanking them before the interview happens. That's really the whole point of my question, whether I ought to thank them for allowing themselves to be interviewed or not. I'm quite sure I can write the rest of the email, it's this part that I'm hung up on.